# Batch File script

Tags: batch-file, dos

Can this looping process be done in a batch file.
Variable that is incremented in the loop then concatenated to do the following

```
VAR=1
Begin Loop
if exist ACHOU.VAR ren ACHOU.VAR ACHOU.VAR.ACE
VAR=VAR+1
if VAR =100 go to END

:END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set /a VAR=1
:Loop
if exist ACHOU.%VAR% ren ACHOU.%VAR% ACHOU.%VAR%.ACE
set /a VAR=%VAR%+1
if %VAR% == 100 goto END 
goto :loop
:END
```

better code (does exactly the same):

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do (
  if exist "ACHOU.%%i" ren "ACHOU.%%i" "ACHOU.%%i.ACE"
)
```